# Make form run a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I make my form run a function when submit is clicked?

```
<form id="commentForm" name="comment">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name <span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="text" id="name" value="" />
        <label for="email">Email <span>(will not be published) (required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="text" id="email" value="" />
        <label for="website">Website</label>
        <input type="text" class="text" id="website" value="" />
        <label for="message">Message <span>(required)</span></label>
        <textarea id="message" class="textarea" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit Comment" action="JavaScript: ajax_add_comment();">
    </fieldset>
    ...
```

I am trying running the following function:

```
function ajax_add_comment () {
    alert ("testing");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form Submit Execute Javascript Best Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), and use the [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function.
You can give the form an `id` and then attach the submit function to it.

Example:

```
<form id="execute"....

</form>

<script type="javascript">
$("#execute").submit(function(){
 alert("i've submitted this form");
});
</script>
```

make sure you have included the jquery js file.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `onclick` attribute instead of `action`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onsubmit` event to execute JavaScript code when the form is submitted. For example:

```
<script>
function ajax_add_comment () {
  alert ("testing");
}
</script>

<form id="commentForm" name="comment">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label for="name">Name <span>(required)</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="text" id="name" value="" />
                                <label for="email">Email <span>(will not be published) (required)</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="text" id="email" value="" />
                                <label for="website">Website</label>
                                <input type="text" class="text" id="website" value="" />                                                                
                                <label for="message">Message <span>(required)</span></label>
                                <textarea id="message" class="textarea" rows="10"></textarea>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit Comment" onsubmit="ajax_add_comment();">
                            </fieldset>
```

Thank you!