# PHP Issues with forms and refreshing/storing data

Tags: php, forms, validation, session

as a first venture into PHP I've decided to try to make a basic Hangman game. I have the majority of my logic for it already done out, but I've run into major problems in working out how to go about taking the user input and using it.

Ideally I'd like to have a text box with a submit button. I'd like to validate the input to ensure that only a lower case input has been entered and then assuming it's all alright, then enter the letter into an array that will be displayed below the submit form.

Basically I want the user input to be directed to my function without refreshing the page entirely and losing all the data. Is there anyway to go about this? I've been looking across this site and the only things people seem to recommend are ajax/jquery and sessions, all of which seem quite complicated and difficult to learn as a beginner. I've tried multiple things recommended on this site and I just can't quite wrap my head around it. I just want some very basic functionality as this is very early into my learning and understanding of PHP.

```
<?php

function comparison()
{   
$theWord ="test";
$theSplit = str_split($theWord);
$currentWord = array(); 
$lettersGuessed = array();
$guessAttempts = 7;
$score = 0;

print_r($theSplit)."<br>";

for($i=0;$i<count($theSplit);$i++)
{
    $currentWord[$i] = "_";
}

print_r($currentWord)."<br>";

$userLetter = "o";

  if (ctype_lower($userLetter)) 
    {
        echo "The user-submitted letter is lowercase. Niceness!<br>";
    } 

  else 
    {
        echo "Invalid submission pigeon-face. Only lowercase letters please muches.<br>";
    }

  if(strpos($theWord,$userLetter) !== false)
    {
        echo "This word contains the letter ".$userLetter."<br>";
        $score++;   
    }

  else
    {
        echo "This word does not contain the letter ".$userLetter."<br>";
        $guessAttempts--;   
    }

$start = 0;

while(($pos = strpos($theWord, $userLetter, $start)) !== false)
    {
        $start = $pos + 1;
        $currentWord[$pos] = $userLetter;
    }

foreach ($currentWord as $letter)
{
    echo $letter." ";
}

array_push($lettersGuessed,$userLetter);
//print_r($lettersGuessed);
print_r($score);
print_r($guessAttempts);

}
?>
```

This is the rough main logic I'm using for the game, but obviously I'd like to have the user submitted letter take the place of the manually assigned value of my $userLetter variable. I'll also be writing a word generator later as well.

This code while obviously quite basic does most of what I think the game would need to, I'd just like to get the submit thing working and have it not ruin the display/array of the word as it gets solved etc.

I realise this is a bit of a poorly worded question but I hope people can understand the nature of my issues, and are willing to help out a noob.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could call a Javascript function on form submission, and use that to do your validation.

See this question: [Form Submit Execute Javascript Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice)

The validation logic looks quite simple, so you should be able to write a JavaScript function which checks the form data, and then does a full post if it checks out. The JavaScript function can also manipulate the page to display errors and so forth.

If the validation needs to be server side, you will either need to do another call using AJAX, or reload the whole page.