# Disabling submit button after click stops form from submitting properly

Tags: jquery, html, forms

One for the puzzle solvers.

I want to disable the submit button to prevent double submissions.

To do this, I use jQuery:

```
jQuery('#subnewtopicform').on('submit', function () {
    jQuery('#subnewtopic').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

And stripped down HTML:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post" id="subnewtopicform">
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtopic" id="subnewtopic" /> 
</form>
```

When clicking submit button, it gets disabled and the page reloads but the form is not properly submitted, **why**?! Removing the jQuery code will make it submit properly.

In my 10 years of coding, I am yet to come across something this strange.

Comment: Is a request ever executed to the server with the content of the form?

Comment: @NathanTaylor I am suspecting that the content is never sent, which makes no sense.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Are you suspecting or do you know for sure? That is key.

Comment: @FastTrack No actual data is sent as far as I know. Any good way to check?

Comment: `ctrl+shift+i` or `f12` in Firefox will bring up the developer tools. Make sure jQuery is being loaded before the javascript function, if the js function is being called when `submit` is pressed, check the neetwork tab of the developer tools to see if any post request is being made. As of right now, I can't replicate this error. My local test works fine to disable the button by still post.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Does your IDE have debugging capabilities? I use NetBeans for my IDE and what I do is set a breakpoint in the PHP file (in your case `file.php`) and from there you can see what's sent and what's not. If you are using jQuery AJAX calls, instead of what you're doing now, you could use Firebug in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: What do you mean by "not properly submitted"?

Comment: @ Dhanushka  see my down voted answer and comments where I clearly lay out that it is either the return or his backend and we require more info.  Please if you agree up vote.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code out. I don't get an error.

```
<form action="file.php" method="post" id="subnewtopicform">
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtopic" id="subnewtopic" /> 
</form>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#subnewtopicform').on('submit', function(e) {
        $('#subnewtopic').prop('disabled', true);
        // e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Things to keep in mind:

- The `POST` action will be too quick for you to see the disabled button. Uncomment `e.preventDefault()` below `$("#subnewtopic.prop('disabled', true);` to test that it works.
- jQuery must be enabled before trying to use this function.
- Use the Developer Tools of either Firefox or Chrome to inspect the Javascript Console for any errors, and the Network Tab to see if any request was posted.

Other than that, this should be pretty straightforward. Like I said, I get no error, it's odd that you are, and probably something very simple. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Could you please confirm, did you perform any changes to my initial code? I checked the network tab and requests were posted.

Comment: Very slight, added `(e)` to the function and made sure jQuery was attached, and changed all instances of `jquery` to `$` as is convention. What happens if you uncomment `e.preventDefault();` Does the post still happen? What happens to the button? Also, the reason so few changes were made is I couldn't replicate the error with your initial code. It worked for me just fine.

Comment: @tim lewis jQuery is convention over $ as $ is reserved by many technologies.  $ is the shorthand version of jQuery.

Comment: @Buck3y3 Maybe, but 99% of jQuery questions are `$("#something")` and not `jquery("#something")`, which is what I was getting at.

Comment: @tim lewis yes but his way was better than what you changed it to. And then you tried to tell him that your way is convention when they both are.  Lets just try and put out the correct info.

Comment: @Buck3y3 Better is a matter of opinion, and all I meant by `convention` was more people use `$` than they do `jquery`. Sorry if that was the wrong word.

Comment: @tim lewis its actually not opinion.  There is no argument against jQuery besides "I dont like to type 5 chars when 1 will do".  The argument against  $ is that long before jquery and even to this day many other things reserve $ as something. This is a hashed out argument all over SO and the rest of the internet.

Comment: @tim lewis I'm trying to rack up more down votes and inform while also entertaining anyone following along ;)

Comment: @Buck3y3 Sure. Anyway, I understand your opinion on the matter, but any further comments from you will be flagged as abusive or non-constructive.

Answer (score -4):

make sure to return true in the jquery function or the server submit will not happen
(thats for the case of error checking)

UPDATE:

```
jQuery('#subnewtopicform').on('submit', function () {
    jQuery('#subnewtopic').prop('disabled', true);
    return true; 
});
```

see:
[Form Submit Execute Javascript Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice)

not sure why he has return false in that answer, I thought it was true.  Try both.

Comment: This is better as a comment, doesn't completely answer the question.

Comment: didn't think that it was complicated enough of an answer to need to write out the code.  This is also a question asked and answered all the time in many places.

Comment: PPS.If this is not the cause then the cause is surely in your backend and we will need much more info.

Comment: I'd love to hear why the down vote?  There is nothing "wrong" about my code not answer.  It may not be the absolute cause but in no way is it wrong.  I actually tested this in a small web forms app and it works fine.

Comment: lol at another down vote without the wherewithal to discuss why or what should be the answer.

Comment: This answer is completely false. The onsubmit event *does not* block form submission by default. `return true` at the end does nothing.