# Call AJAX to send value with button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, button

I read a lot of similar questions, and I tried all solutions but nothing seems to work. I want to send an AJAX request by clicking a button and send what the user typed in a *textarea* and display it in a *div*(chatbox). When I click the button, nothing happens. It never calls the function that has the AJAX code. Do you have any ideas what is going on?

P.S. I included the JavaScript files but nothing's changed.

```js
<form action="ajax()">
    <textarea id="txtArea" name="txtArea" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

 //AJAX function
function ajax() {
    alert("insert");
    var txtArea = $("#txtArea").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "InsertMessage.php",
        data: {
            txtArea: txtArea
        }
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#chatbox").load("DisplayMessages.php")
            $("#txtArea").val(""); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div    
        }
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error, write your error handling code here.');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(startAjax);
//setInterval(function(){
// $("#chatbox").load("DisplayMessages.php");  
//}//,1400);
 
</script>
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think `action` is if you want the browser to make a request for you, have you tried changing `<form action="ajax()">` to `<form onsubmit="ajax()">`? [W3Schools Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), [Form Submit Execute Javascript Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice)

Comment: yes i tried but nothing..

Answer (score 1):

The `action` attribute has to contain a URL, not Javascript. You can use:

```
<form action="javascript:ajax()">
```

or:

```
<form onsubmit="ajax(); return false;">
```

or you can bind the event in jQUery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        ajax();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: the only thing that do after these changes is to overload the page but still seems to ignore the function

Comment: If you use `onsubmit`, you also need to `return false;` to prevent the normal form submission. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear, But for sending data in post method when submiting a form and then show result in a div, try something like this:

html:

```
    <form>
        <textarea id="txtArea" name="txtArea" ></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <div id="resultDiv">
    </div>
```

js:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var txtArea = $("#txtArea").val();
    $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"InsertMessage.php",
                data:{txtArea:txtArea}
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);                        
                    $("#resultDiv").html(data);           
                }
                error: function(){
                     alert('there was an error, write your error handling code here.');
                }
        });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but nothing is change...i call php to insert the values tha write the user and after that with this  "$("#chatbox").load("DisplayMessages.php")   
    $("#txtArea").val(""); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div "
will dislay it in the div "chatbox" 
But still don't call the function.. :/