# javascript: loop through elements and change their values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

**My code doesn't change element values**
I'm working in Visual Studio 2017 with cordova inAppBrowser and I'm not sure why it doesn't work? My code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
  elements[i].innerHTMl = "sometext";
}
```

I want my code to change each element. I appreciate your help

Comment: It works fine now with divs, but I used the same thing but with forms and elements[i].onSubmit = 'function(){ alert(string) }'; and it doesn't work on submiting a form, I also checked code with alert and it stays unchanged the whole time. If you have any idea why it doesn't work I would be soo thankful to you

Comment: I've found out the soulution for my problem. onsubmit didn't work for me so I used elements[i].action = 'javascript:myFunction();';  to do javascript action instead of redirecting page. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, it's `innerHTML` not `innerHTMl` here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j8nbdm6b/2/

Comment: Why you put consol.log? Is it necessary?

Comment: it is not, you can remove it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check if it works in my full code and probably mark your answer as the best one

Comment: I used the same thing but with forms and elements[i].onSubmit = 'function(){ alert(string) }'; and it doesn't work on submiting a form, I also checked code with alert and it stays unchanged the whole time. If you have any idea why it doesn't work I would be soo thankful to you

Comment: Your function is in a String, try passing a real function, I'll edit my fiddle to make it work.

Comment: Thank you! Try adding a <form> and <input type="submit">

Comment: Well i won't code it for you. play around. See how it work,

Comment: just one more question, I did it and it sends alert but not on form submit but on loading page, so am I doing it right? <form onsubmit="submitted()"></form> ?

Comment: are you sure you added the onsubmit on the form, rather than on the parent element, ( `<div class="parent" onsubmit="submit()"><form></form></div>`) ?

Comment: I'm sure "elements[i].onSubmit = submitted(); " and elements are all <form>

Comment: try adding it to the action rather than on submit `elements[i].action = myFunc()`

Comment: I tried it before and it sent me to error page not found... I'll try again, but thanks anyways

Comment: You can try to refer to this question for more example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice

Comment: I found out that it changes action on elements[i].action = function() {myFunction()};  but it is no good because it sees it as a page URL, but onsubmit stays the same on elements[i].onsubmit = function() {myFunction()};  Anyways I'll try to figure out how to use action for this, probably I'll need javascript: before my code

Comment: I found out the solution elements[i].action = 'javascript:myFunction();';  should I put solution somewhere in this question? Because I'm new member on stack

Comment: i'll just upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

`elements[i].innerHTMl` should read `elements[i].innerHTML` (uppercase L)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lowercase L in innerHTML...

Here's a working demo

```
    (function() {
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      getDivs();
    })
  })()

  function getDivs() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        console.log(elements);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
        elements[i].innerHTML = "sometext" + i;
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h7cgmxmf/