# Trying to make two functions associate with one button using Type= and OnClick=

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, disabled-input

I am working on a webpage where a Submit button sumbits a form, but I also want pressing the button to activate a JavaScript function which will disable the Search button and enable a button to reset the search fields and reenable the search button. This is the code currently on the button:

```
<input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="SearchOff()"></input>
```

And this is the code currently behind that JavaScript function:

```
function SearchOff() {
     document.getElementById("Search").disabled = true;
     document.getElementById("Reset_Search").disabled = false;
     document.getElementById("[All other relevant fields]").disabled = true;
     var x = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
     x[0].submit();// Form submission
     return true;
}
```

(I have anonymised the actual function of the application, but it is just entering data into a form which is processed by other JavaScript)

The JavaScript does work, but when `onclick="SearchOff()"` is in the code, the `type=submit` function is overridden. Is there any way to get both functions to work? As you can see, I have tried this already with the bottom 2 lines of the JS code, but that was done without `onclick="SearchOff()"` in the code. I have also tried without this, and had the same problem.

How can I make both functions work at the same time?

Comment: [See this... Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. I tried <form action="#" [other th:action/th:object code] method="post" onsubmit="return SearchOff();"> at the start of my form, and got the same result.

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 The first line of my form now looks like this: '<form action="#" th:action="@{/mapWithRoutes}" th:object="${searchCriteria}" method="post" onsubmit="return SearchOff();" Onreset="return SearchOn();">' (I am  also trying to do the reverse, i.e. enable the search buttons and other fields when the Reset button is pressed. Both of these functions now work, but the form is still not submitting. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGNBad?editors=1010) idea?

```
function searchOff(event) {
  //No submission yet.
  event.preventDefault();

  //Disable buttons.
  document.querySelector('[type=submit]').disabled = 'disabled';

  //Submit the form.
  document.querySelector('form').submit();
}
```

Prevent the form submission when the button is clicked, disable the buttons you need to disable and then, submit the form yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try retyping the formulas from scratch, which worked onthis occasion for some reason. I think the key was to not copy and paste any of the actual formula, and instead only copy the text to be searched for and counted. This is all I did differently, and I hope reading this helps someone out who reads this.