# Run JavaScript and php on one button

Tags: javascript, php

Can we run a js function on a submit button and php on the same button. I have a submit button that sends form data to a database using php, but I want a second action (JavaScript function) to take place once the button is clicked as well. Is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried already before asking the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form Submit Execute JavaScript Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice)

Answer (score 3):

You can add `onclick()` event to submit button. it will execute before submitting the form.

```js
var buttonClick = () => {
  alert("Do what you want to do!"); // Add your second work here
}
```

```html
<form action="yourfile.php">
    <input type="submit" onclick="buttonClick();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct method is to call the javascript function on the onsubmit attribute in the form with a return state. Thus the form will wait until the JavaScript returns true before proceeding with submit.

**The HTML**

```
<form action="something.php" onsubmit="return someJsFunction()">
<!-- form elements -->
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**The JavaScript**

```
  function someJsFunction(){

     //your validations or code

     if(condition == false){
       return false; // This will prevent the Form from submitting and lets 
                     // you show error message or do some actions
     }else{
       return true; // this will submit the form and handle the control to php.
     }
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with the jQuery submit callback for this

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    alert("Submitted");
});
```

see. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_submit.asp