# Django How to redirect AJAX Loaded form to previous state on unsuccessful submission

Tags: django, ajax

I have got a template A.html which contains a link that processes an AJAX request, goes to a view, loads a form in B.html that is returned in AJAX success to a div specified in A.html. Now I have a view that on form submission goes to forms.py and gets that form cleaned and a validation error is raised. Where should I redirect my view if I want the previous state of A.html to be preserved? [image: Workflow of my project]

PS: This might be a bad design. But I am a beginner in Django, and have read that to not refresh a page depending on selection of some fields, we need to use AJAX calls. Now fields F1 and F2 determine what will be loaded in div. So I used AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Okay I will try to help you now the question is clearer.

There are two ways of solving this problem.

The first one (that I personally prefer) will consist on validating the View 2 form with an AJAX call. For doing so you have to execute a function when the form is going to be submitted. (Check out this post if you don't know how: [Form Submit Execute JavaScript Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice)). Then the AJAX response will be a list of form errors, if there are no errors the AJAX success function will redirect to A.html otherwise the function will set the errors with jQuery and wait to another form submit.

The second one consists on rendering A.html with B.html already inside in the view post function if the `form.is_valid()` returns `False`. In this case, B.html form will be a validated one and it will contain the proper errors inside. In the other hand, if the `form.is_valid()`returns `True` you can just redirect to A.html.

I know it could be hard to implement this for the first time, so think about it and if you need extra help with the code I will gladly edit the message again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into this. I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: In my clean method, I filter from models, so in that case can I use Javascript to do so?

Comment: Hi Nisha, can you post the code of the views? It will be much easier to help you. But answering you, after doing an AJAX request the post method of your view will be executed, then you can validate your form in that function (backend) and return the list of errors. Tomorrow I'll include some code to help you understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you put REST api driven ajax calls to Django views and render on client side ?

Comment: By render on client do you mean a Django client?

Comment: @Nisha no. By render on client I mean by using JS client side library. May be template rendering on client side.

Comment: I have made the whole project in Django, and the deadline is very close. Using a JS client side library is not an option right now.

Comment: @Nisha the idea is not to scrap django. The idea is to use Django as REST API service. And use JS frameworks like React or Angular to render the template. Django stays there but in a different way. Your back end logic is going to be the same. Instead of passing your context variables in django templates you will return them back to client.  Also if that is time consuming here and you are short of time, in the you showed above, can’t we pass the validation errors to that form page  itself? You can show the error messages below each form field ? I hope i got your problem clearly.

Comment: I did just that, but it will load only C. html that contains form,but ideally C.html should be in B. html inside A. html