# using a hyperlink to change style.display

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, input, href

currently, I have a hyperlink with an empty href. the initial goal was that I have an input number element witch the div's display changes (`style.display = 'none';`) and then the hyperlink pops up so the user can change the display to inline or flex (`style.display = 'inline';`)
here are my HTML and JavaScript the display changes explained are in the `else` section of the if statement

HTML:

```
<div class="preT" id="preT">
  <form>
    <label for="voipLines">VoIP Lines</label>
    <input type="number" id="voipLines" name="voipLines" required min="1" max="1000" value="1">
    <button class="button" onclick="testfun()">Test Clicker</button>
  </form>
  <div class="voipbutton" id="voipbutton">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="duringT">
  <p Id="clickerTest"></p>
  <div Id="prBar" data-label=""></div>
  <div id="canvascon"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function testfun() {
  var voip = document.getElementById("voipLines").value;
  if (voip < 1) { //voiplines verification 
    return document.getElementById("clickerTest").innerHTML = "<div><p>Make Sure VoIP Lines is within the range of 1 to 1000</p></div>";
  } else if (voip > 1000) {
    return document.getElementById("clickerTest").innerHTML = "<div><p>Make Sure VoIP Lines is within the range of 1 to 1000</p></div>";
  } else { // Trying to move the button within the form element
    document.getElementById("clickerTest").innerHTML = '<h2 id="testT">Clicker Successful!!!</h2><p>Please click the link below to start <b>' + voip + ' test</b></p><p id="reset">To change the amount of tests to run <a href= "">Click Here</a></p>';
  }
```

PS.

I plan on making a separate forum for this but I figured if anyone knows this solution, it would be nice.

If anyone has any ideas from what is shown:

The if statement is looping ever since I put the button from `<div id = "VoIP button">` and into the `<form>` tag. when I put a number that is <0 or >1000 it provides the proper text. but when I put a number that is within the range the canvas and following functions show for just a second then loop back to show `<div id="preT">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close! In the HTML 5 spec, a `<button>` inside of a form has a default type of `submit` Your javascript runs, and the page imediately "submits" to load the next page. Simply adding `type="button"` will prevent this and stop submitting the form.

```js
function testfun() {
  var voip = document.getElementById("voipLines").value;
  if (voip < 1) { //voiplines verification 
    return document.getElementById("clickerTest").innerHTML = "<div><p>Make Sure VoIP Lines is within the range of 1 to 1000</p></div>";
  } else if (voip > 1000) {
    return document.getElementById("clickerTest").innerHTML = "<div><p>Make Sure VoIP Lines is within the range of 1 to 1000</p></div>";
  } else { // Trying to move the button within the form element
    document.getElementById("clickerTest").innerHTML = '<h2 id="testT">Clicker Successful!!!</h2><p>Please click the link below to start <b>' + voip + ' test</b></p><p id="reset">To change the amount of tests to run <a href= "">Click Here</a></p>';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="preT" id="preT">
  <form>
    <label for="voipLines">VoIP Lines</label>
    <input type="number" id="voipLines" name="voipLines" required min="1" max="1000" value="1">
    <button class="button" type="button" onclick="testfun()">Test Clicker</button>
  </form>
  <div class="voipbutton" id="voipbutton">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="duringT">
  <p Id="clickerTest"></p>
  <div Id="prBar" data-label=""></div>
  <div id="canvascon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm ok, now that works thank you for making that a super clear explanation. BUT, Why does using the return/enter button not do anything though? I guess it's not that big of a problem but that was the point of moving the button tag.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is not really a button, but rather modifying the `onsubmit` functionality of your form. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8082928/7314155 for more information.

Comment: I did some research based on that link's info provided and stumbled on event listeners. but the same thing was happening. I ran into a youtube video that used `event.preventDefault();` and added that in at the beginning of my function. works like a charm but im not sure if that would effecting anything else in the function.

Comment: @mastaSabin I didn't want to take the fun out of it. That's the right solution, and a good learning discovery.

Comment: My "mentor" figure is telling me that my if statement is not working as intended because the variable voip is a string and that I should look up `function parseInt()` and incorporate it. he didn't explain much other than that, would you mind explaining why it needs to be an integer instead of a string? Dont mind me i dont know anybody who knows javascript other than him.

Comment: @mastaSabin I reached out to you in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216181/john-mastasabin).