# How do I execute a JS function on form submit based on commands entered in text input?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I take this form and execute certain functions when a specific text is entered to trigger the event?

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Command" id="text" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>

function RUN() {
    // when run is entered in text field this function is exe

}

function CLOSE() {
    // when close is entered in text field this function is exe

}
```

example commands: RUN and CLOSE

EDIT something i got kinda working:

How do I make multiple commands exe different functions? This works without the second or third command added. Once I add multiple the only one that works is the one at the bottom.

```
            function readCommand() {
                let readInput = document.querySelector('#SearchBar').value
                //           ↓ no .value, it's already here -----------↑
                if (readInput === 'RUN') {
                    //             ↑ === vs =
                    CMDRUN()
                } else {
                    alert(`Not a command`);
                }
            }

            function readCommand() {
                let readInput = document.querySelector('#SearchBar').value
                //           ↓ no .value, it's already here -----------↑
                if (readInput === 'CLOSE') {
                    //             ↑ === vs =
                    CMDCLOSE()
                } else {
                    alert(`Not a command`);
                }
            }

            function CMDRUN() {
                alert ("This is an alert dialog box 1");  
            }

            function CMDCLOSE() {
                alert ("This is an alert dialog box 2");  
            }
```

Comment: U should create a function that does exactly that (check the input and call appropriate function) and then call it on submit

Comment: I dont know how **sad face**

Comment: Try looking for your answer on this site.  There are a TON of questions with answers pertaining to how to call a JavaScript function on form submit.  If you encounter a problem with your attempt, update your question and 1) show us what you have tried and 2) explain at what point you aren't getting the result you expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form Submit Execute JavaScript Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082846/form-submit-execute-javascript-best-practice)

Comment: kinda but not quite i added an edit with something i got working half way. What i did only works for one command i need multiple.

Comment: sorry im new to js

Comment: You keep redefining the “readCommand” function. You likely want multiple if/else, or a switch statement.

Comment: do i use else? to add more if statements?

Comment: figured it out with your guidence

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using an onsubmit event along with the window object to call a function using the string input.

When the form is submitted, the value of the input box is the function that will be executed.

```js
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function() {
  window[document.getElementById("text").value]();
}

function RUN() {
// when run is entered in text field this function is exe

}

function CLOSE() {
// when close is entered in text field this function is exe

}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Command" id="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I added a edit with something i got kinda working maybe you can help me figure out how to add multiple commands to that code?

Comment: It appears you overrode your readCommand function with another variation of the function. That is why you can only call one command.

Comment: I suggest you use if/else statements to call multiple commands. Check out https://jsfiddle.net/vobg0j5u/.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function readCommand() {
        let readInput = document.querySelector('#SearchBar').value

        if (readInput === 'RUN') {
                        CMDRUN()
        } else if (readInput === 'CLOSE') {
                        CMDCLOSE()
        } else {
                        alert(`Not a command`);
        }

    }

    function CMDRUN() {
         alert ("This is an alert dialog box 1");  
    }

    function CMDCLOSE() {
         alert ("This is an alert dialog box 2");  
    }
```

```html
<form name="SearchContainer" id="SearchContainer" class="WindowMenuUp">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search and Commands" name="SearchBar" id="SearchBar" class="SearchBar" />
         <input type="button" value="Search" name="SearchButton" id="SearchButton" class="SearchButton" onclick="readCommand()" />
    </form>
```